# Google Doc - Public shareable link

Tags: google-docs

I have a bunch of documents for which I want to determine the public links. Reading https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494822?hl=en says I can get a "Anyone with a shareable link".

However no matter what I do I cannot find that option. The only links I can get is for ".... in the Organisation" All I need to do is get the link so I can embed it in an iFrame on another site.

Can anyone give me any pointers. This is not obvious as I think the fact it is in a Google Apps environment is preventing me getting what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not see the option, likely your administrator has restricted sharing with outside sources. You will need to speak with your domain administrator to either change these settings, or to figure out an alternative method of sharing the document.

Your administrator can find this in `Apps > Google Apps > Drive > Sharing settings` in the admin console.
https://support.google.com/a/answer/60781?hl=en